# send data to an array from 2 collection select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have controller with an action step2 which collects all devices by selected category. My step2.html.erb looks like:

```
<% form_for compare_comparision_path, :url => {:action => 'comparision'} do |f| %>  
  <%= f.collection_select(:device, @devices, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select"}, :class=>'device') %>
    </br>
 <%= f.collection_select(:device, @devices, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select"}, :class=>'device') %>
    <%= f.submit 'ok' %>
<% end %>
```

I want for it to allow the user to select two devices and send it to some array or variable in comparison action.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
<% form_for compare_comparision_path, :url => {:action => 'comparision'} do |f| %>  
  <%= f.collection_select('device[]', @devices, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select"}, :class=>'device') %>
    </br>
 <%= f.collection_select('device[]', @devices, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select"}, :class=>'device') %>
    <%= f.submit 'ok' %>
<% end %>
```

and in controller you`ll have an array in params[:device] containing to selected values.

Or you can replace 'device[]' in my example with unique name for each selectbox (for example 'devise1' and 'device2'.

Then you can get selected values in controller by accessing params[:device1] and params[:device2]

Comment: by your example i am getting Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"ā“",
 "authenticity_token"=>"DQvhmzHrIi0tdVZOfJQI8JdZq+p6FturXCApD/bYvYA=",
 "/compare/comparision"=>{"device1"=>[nil]},
 "commit"=>"palyginti"}